# mongo not showing users even though I "know" they exist

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to implement a authentication system for my website using MEAN however I have run into a relatively strange problem. I am able to register users and duplicate usernames can be identified. However, I cannot get logging into the website working. When I search the mongo database using the command line, I do not get anything. This is what my mongo output looks like.

```
>> show users 
>>
```

The database has the username somewhere... so how do I get the users to be properly displayed? Why is that user is undefined when I try to log in even though I know the username is in the database?

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = mongoose.model('User');

function hashPW(pwd) {
    return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(pwd).digest('base64').toString();
};

module.exports.signup = function (req,res) {
    var user = new User({username:req.body.usernmae});
    console.log('made it here');

    user.set('hashed_password', hashPW(req.body.password));
    user.set('email', req.body.email);

    user.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            try {
                if (err.code==11000) res.render('signup', {message: 'Sorry, someone has that username already.'})
            } catch(e) {

            }
            console.log(err);
            //res.redirect('/signup');
        } else {
            req.session.user = user.id;
            req.session.username = user.username;
            req.session.msg = 'Authenticated as ' + user.username;
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    });
};

module.exports.login = function (req,res) {
    User.findOne({ username: req.body.username })
        .exec(function(err,user) {
            console.log(user);
            console.log(err);
            console.log(hashPW(req.body.password.toString()));

            if (!user) {
                err = 'User Not Found.';
            } else if ( user.password === hashPW( req.body.password.toString() ) ) {
                req.session.regenerate(function() {
                    req.session.user = user.id;
                    req.session.username = user.username;
                    req.session.msg = 'Authenticated as ' + user.username;
                    res.redirect('/');
                });
            } else {
                err = 'Authentication failed.';
            }

            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                req.session.regenerate(function() {
                    req.session.msg = err;
                    res.redirect('/login');
                });
            }
        });
};
```

Comment: with the exception of "show dbs" and "show collections" the form of "show" you are expecting is used by SQL and not mongodb. That form of show would be invalid as there is no schema for documents in a collection to conform to. If you just want to verify it's there then just `db.users.find()`

Answer (score 0):

I notice that there's a typo in the provided code.

```
var user = new User({username:req.body.usernmae});
```

Should likely read

```
var user = new User({username:req.body.username});
```

This probably meant the name failed to set thus putting a junk user into your DB.

Also, regarding your command in the Mongo Shell, Neil's answer covered that the show command is not actually useful here. [The reference for db.collection.find() is here.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)

Comment: good eye. had to read it over a few times before I realized my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

silly mistake. the field is not `password` but `hashed_password`.

```
{ email: 'somerandomemail@gmail.com',
  hashed_password: 'A8ctR3JAA84DWTmYXEAhxEEP1bTtAidaoyWArKHtk2g=',
  username: 'Szpok',
  _id: 54c09c458c4eccc90b9c4bb5,
  __v: 0 }
```